# Proof verification that the midpoint of a linear equation is the average

Tags: integration, proof-verification, average

Given some function $f(x)=mx+b$ on the interval $[j,k]$, does this prove that $f({{j+k}\over2})$, (the midpoint), is equal to the average value of $f$ on $[j,k]$?

If, using the midpoint formula: $M(a,b)={{a+b}\over2}$
$$A_1={{f(k)+f(j)}\over2}=f({{k+j}\over2})\\={m\over2}(k+j)+b$$
And, using the average formula: $A(a,b)={{\int_a^b{f(x)}}\over{b-a}}$
$$A_2={{\int_j^k{mx+b}}\over{k-j}}\\={{{m\over2}k^2+bk-\big({{m\over2}j^2+bj}\big)}\over{k-j}}\\={{m\over2}(k+j)+b}$$
Then: $A_1=A_2$, which implies that the midpoint is the average.

Comment: The work looks good; but, the documentation could be better.  You should state you are going to use the midpoint formula and give it before using it.  Same with the average forrmula (instead of just throwing them in the proof).

Comment: @danpost thanks, I'll edit it in tonight or tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

Yes - this proved the desired result.  Your proof could be a little more formal but that does not alter the result.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would you do to improve it?

Comment: There are several ways to make this clearer.  One is to simply find the mean of the x values and then the mean of the f(x) values and then show that both are on the same line as the original.  In any case, these all depend on the fact that the relationship is LINEAR. However, your proof is still correct.